# Nome 'driver' não está definido

Tags: python

Estou fazendo esse bot para acessar o instagram, mas está apresentando um erro que não consigo identificar. Sou um iniciante e estou com problemas para encontrar o erro. Se alguém puder me ajudar, agradeço!!

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import random

class InstagramBot:
    def __init__(self, username, password):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r"C:\Users\bruno\Desktop\geckodriver-v0.29.1-win64\geckodriver.exe")
           
    def login(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?hl=pt-br")
   
    campo_usuario = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='username']")
    campo_usuario.click()
    campo_usuario.clear()
    campo_usuario.send_keys(self.username)
    campo_senha = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='password']")
    campo_senha.click()
    campo_senha.clear()
    campo_senha.send_keys(self.password)
    campo_senha.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
 
   
brunoBot = InstagramBot("user","senha1234")  
brunoBot.login()
```

Erro:

````
File "c:\Users\bruno\Desktop\geckodriver-v0.29.1-win64\igBot.py", line 16, in InstagramBot
campo_usuario = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='username']")
NameError: name 'driver' is not defined
PS C:\Users\bruno\Desktop\geckodriver-v0.29.1-win64>```

Obrigado! :)
````

Comment: Acredito que as linhas a partir de `campo_usuario` estejam identadas de forma errada. Inclua 4 espaços para cada uma delas.

Answer (score 1):

Alguns pontos precisam ser corrigidos no teu código para que funcione corretamente, vamos lá?

```
login(self):
    driver = self.driver
    driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?hl=pt-br")

campo_usuario = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='username']")
campo_usuario.click()
campo_usuario.clear()
campo_usuario.send_keys(self.username)
campo_senha = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='password']")
campo_senha.click()
campo_senha.clear()
campo_senha.send_keys(self.password)
campo_senha.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

Na função login, primeiramente você deve **identar corretamente seu código** para que fique dentro da função. A identação é algo fundamental na linguagem python para delimitação dos blocos de código, o mau uso pode acarretar no mal funcionamento do seu sistema. Então ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
def login(self):
    driver = self.driver
    driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?hl=pt-br")
    campo_usuario = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='username']")
    campo_usuario.click()
    campo_usuario.clear()
    campo_usuario.send_keys(self.username)
    campo_senha = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='password']")
    campo_senha.click()
    campo_senha.clear()
    campo_senha.send_keys(self.password)
    campo_senha.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

Uma dica.. ainda na função "login" você não precisaria criar a variável "driver" com o valor "self.driver", pois logo acima no construtor "__ init__" você já o criou como "self.driver". O que isso quer dizer? O **"self"** serve para que você referencie o próprio objeto(instância) tanto quando você for fazer uso de metódos como quando for utilizar atributos pertencentes e este objeto. Então desta forma você pode acessar o seu "self.driver" em qualquer lugar dentro da tua classe e a estrutura ficaria assim:

```
def login(self):
    self.driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?hl=pt-br")
    campo_usuario = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='username']")
    campo_usuario.click()
    campo_usuario.clear()
    campo_usuario.send_keys(self.username)
    campo_senha = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='password']")
    campo_senha.click()
    campo_senha.clear()
    campo_senha.send_keys(self.password)
    campo_senha.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

Comment: Opa, valeu pela dica!!

Comment: Entendi amigo, show de bola!! muito obrigado pela ajuda!!